# Xcode Default Optimization Level?

Tags: iphone, xcode, compiler-construction

Can anyone confirm the default options I should be using for compiler optimisation. I remember I changed this whilst Xcode4 was in preview to work round a bug, but now I can't remember what it was set to before (i.e. by default).

I currently have it set to:

```
Debug: Fastest, Smallest [-Os]
Release: Fastest, Smallest [-Os]
```

I am pretty sure it should be: (but wanted to check)

```
Debug: None [-O0]
Release: Fastest, Smallest [-Os]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes `None -O0`.
With -O1 or greater optimizations, the compiler try to optimize part of the code (loops, instruction swap and others) making it harder to do a step by step debug.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a new project and checking the settings tells me you're correct.

Answer (score 1):

The default values in Xcode 8.2.1 are:
Apple LLVM Optimization mode: Fastest, Smallest [-Os] 
Optimization mode for Swift: Fast, Whole module optimization [-O -whole-module-optmization]